# Converting PySerial Code from Python 3 to 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyserial

I'm trying to port a program written in Python 3.5 to 2.7, but it seems the addition of bytes objects in Python 3 changes how PySerial is implemented. Unfortunately, *I cannot find any documentation for PySerial 2.x*, so I would greatly appreciate help converting this code from PySerial 3 to 2:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM6', 9600)

ser.write(bytes(chr(0x30), 'UTF-8'))
dataIn = ser.read(size=4)
```

Since the `bytes` object is just an alias for the `str` type in Python 2.x, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

Does PySerial's `write()` method use a `bytearray` object as the parameter or does it use a `string` with another parameter for the encoding?

What datatype does `ser.read(size=4)` return?

Or better yet if someone has a link to the documentation...

Comment: What about `ser.write(chr(0x30))`? In Python 2 `bytes` (an alias of str) does not take a second argument (the encoding here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I had to literally [use a time machine](https://archive.org/web/) to find PySerial 2's [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20150808165248/http://pyserial.sourceforge.net:80/pyserial_api.html), which no longer exists, but now I can answer my own question:

`ser.write()` accepts a `str` or, indeed, a `bytearray` in Python 2.6+. A `bytearray` is probably better so I can specify the encoding if I want, since a `str`'s encoding seems to depend on [system settings](http://www.ianbicking.org/illusive-setdefaultencoding.html). So my code is now:

```
ser.write(bytearray([0x30]))
```

Also, `ser.read` returns a `str` (or a `bytes` in Py2.6+).